# Recognise other devices positions

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I am currently working on my thesis project, where I am building a Javascript/node library making it easier for developers to merge the canvas in the browser from multiple devices together. So that objects can live within a large canvas of all the devices together. Basically, the idea is that you'll be able to put multiple phones/pads next to each other in different positions relative to each other, but use all their browsers as just one canvas.
I will also create another library extension with a bunch of restrictions to it, and hold a hackathon to see what developers creates with this tool and within these restrictions.

Anyway, I have ran into a problem. To make the tool more versatile and flexible I optimally want every device to be able to detect where in space the other devices are in relation to itself. But I have ran out of ideas about how to solve it, do you guys have any ideas? Do you think it is possible? Or will I have to come up with a manual solution? Can any other technology help? Bluetooth?

I have looked at projects like:

Google Chrome Racer (https:/ /www.chrome.com/racer)

Coca-Cola Penguin Curling (http:/ /cargocollective.com/rafaeldante/Coca-Cola-Penguin-Curling)

How do you think these projects solved the issue of positioning order? Which device is where in the order?

Sadly, Chrome Racer doesn't seem to be running anymore. But as far as I can remember playing it a while ago, you did not have to put in the position of your device manually? Analyzing this clip(https://youtu.be/17P67Uz0kcw?t=4m46s), it looks like the application understands where in line that specific device is, right? Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a random musing on possible paths to a solution.

They all have cameras that are facing up. If any two can capture an image that overlaps you have way of orienting relative to each other. If every device had a view that overlapped with at least one other then you can get a reasonable approximation of the relative orientation and positions of them all. The more devices the better the result.

You can listen to the ambient sound environment and use arrival time of sounds to give another relative positional clue. Devices can also emit both sound and light, if done with pre determined order, the sound can produce relative position. The display if flashed on and off in specific patterns could also be detected ( not directly but as subtle ambient reflection.)

Ambient light levels are also a source of relative position and orientation.

If only two devices tried these methods they would fail most of the time. But with each extra device you get its relative information compared to all the others thus growing the data exponentially making a solution easier to find. Given enough devices the solution of position and orientation may be possible via passive sensing only.